# XpsDocument.FixedDocumentSequenceReader is nothing

Tags: vb.net, xaml, visual-studio-2013, xps, xpsdocument

Ok, so I can't figure this out. I created a quick word .docx in Win 8 using Word 2013.  3-4 lines of text, printed it using Microsoft XPS Document Writer v4. It created an .oxps.  I changed that to a .zip, looked through the pages and read the FixedDocumentSequence.fdseq, the FixedDocument.fdoc, and the one 1.fpage that was generated to make sure the xaml was clean. I also read the glyphs on the page to see if the "UnicodeString" was also there.

Here is my console app code...

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myXPS As New XpsDocument("d:\wordtest.oxps", IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.Packaging.CompressionOption.NotCompressed)        
    Dim reader As IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader = myXPS.FixedDocumentSequenceReader()
End Sub
```

I put a breakpoint at the reader and debug the code.  The object "myXPS' is fine *exept*
 it doesn't have a FixedDocumentSequenceReader. It says "nothing" when looking at the locals.

I have all the references I should, and am importing:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Xps.Packaging
```

Is there any reason for this to happen?

I have VS 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft XPS Document Writer allows you to print to a .xps when you are saving the file. Once I did that, the program worked fine. Apparently vs2013(and 2010) doesn't like the Windows 8 .oxps files. Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

I found from the following link that you should be using a forward slash here:
http://www.michaelflanakin.com/Articles/tabid/143/articleType/ArticleView/ArticleID/496/PageID/26/Default.aspx

e.g.,

```
Dim myXPS As New XpsDocument("d:/wordtest.oxps", ...
```

Comment: I did try that, no luck. The object is still the same regardless of "/" or "\."